# Possible to mass-replace strings in records?

Tags: ms-access

I have about 500 records that have a text field that ends with "nnnn"

I need to replace nnnn with VV.RR, is there any way I can do this without going through each record and replacing them one by one?

Comment: If nnnn and VV.RR are constant strings, you can simply "Replace all" in the Find&Replace dialog. If not, please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: He may also think about an update query (faster when working with 500 rows).